# Using Ceva's Theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A convex hexagon $ABCDEF$ satisfies $|AB|=|BC|;|CD|=|DE|;|EF|=|FA|$.   Prove  that  the  lines  containing  the  altitudes  of  the triangles $BCD$, $DEF$, $FAB$ starting,  respectively,  at  the  vertices $C, E, A$, intersect at a common point.

How can I use Ceva's theorem in order to prove this? Any hints,

Thanks

Comment: Your classmate was faster in asking about homework.

Comment: @Futurologist: If nothing else, this duplicate confirms that the question "wants" a Ceva-based solution, even though each of the current answers to the earlier post (including the ones by you and me) takes a different approach.

Comment: @Blue who knows who suggested Ceva's theorem. Might have been one of the students, who tried to show off after class, saying "Oh this is easy. You just apply Ceva's theorem". The rest believed him and the question ends up in this form on math SE.